# Como retorna um tipo anônimo?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, return

Possuo um método que deveria retornar uma coleção de objetos anônimos:

```
/*Aqui deveria ser o tipo anonimo "AnonymousType"*/
[AnonymousType] ListarAnonimo()
{
    //Especifica um "template" para o tipo retornado.
    var lista = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            Nome = "",
            Idade = 0,
            Salario = 0.0m
        }
    }.ToList();

    lista.Clear();

    //Adiciona um item.
    lista.Add(new
    {
        Nome = "Gato",
        Idade = 25,
        Salario = 3000000.0m
    });

    return lista;
}
```

Tentei fazer com que ele retornasse uma lista de tipo `List<dynamic>` porem desta forma recebi o seguinte erro de compilação:

> Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Então tentei usar o `List<object>` porém recebi o mesmo erro.

---

## Pergunta

Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso retorna um tipo anonimo **AnonymousType** através de um método?

Comment: É difícil responder isso. Existe algum padrão nos tipos que vão ser retornados?

Comment: Os tipos retornados representam uma tabela do banco de dados.

Comment: E qual é a forma que você está tentando usar o retorno deste método? Acho que retornar uma lista de `object` deve funcionar.

Comment: @jbueno o retorno é os campos q estão sendo selecionados através de uma consulta usando o Dapper para retornar um `IEnumerable<dynamic> resultado` porem preciso retornar uma lista tipada para popular um DataGridView através da propriedade `DataSource`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não recomendo fazer assim, é melhor ter uma classe para gerar. De fato este exemplo parece fictício e é desnecessário não ter um tipo. Se quiser insistir garanto que a lista seja de `object`s. Quando receber provavelmente terá que fazer um *cast* para op tipo correto, então é melhor gerá-lo já assim. A não ser que queira jogar no lixo a tipagem estática. Faça assim:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = ListarAnonimo();
    }
        public static List<object> ListarAnonimo() {
        var lista = new object[] {
            new {
                Nome = "",
                Idade = 0,
                Salario = 0.0m
            }
        }.ToList();
        lista.Clear();
        lista.Add(new {
            Nome = "Gato",
            Idade = 25,
            Salario = 3000000.0m
        });
        return lista;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uUcyc9). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KGxRMg). Também [coloquei no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/ReturnAnonymousType.cs).

Você pode usar assim, mas sinceramente, é melhor criar a classe:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = ListarAnonimo();
        foreach (var item in lista) {
            var pessoa = Util.Cast(item, new { Nome = "", Idade = 0, Salario = 0.0m });
            WriteLine($"Nome: {pessoa.Nome} - Idade: {pessoa.Idade} - Salario {pessoa.Salario}");
        }
    }
    public static List<object> ListarAnonimo() {
        var lista = new object[] {
            new {
                Nome = "",
                Idade = 0,
                Salario = 0.0m
            }
        }.ToList();
        lista.Clear();
        lista.Add(new {
            Nome = "Gato",
            Idade = 25,
            Salario = 3000000.0m
        });
        return lista;
    }
}

public static class Util {
    public static T Cast<T>(object obj, T type) => (T)obj;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sg01pg). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7RuHm). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/ReturnAnonymousType2.cs).

Se não quer a classe mesmo, o [C# 7 tem tupla na linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101) mesmo, mas é um belo abuso.

Comment: Pesquisei aqui uma forma tbm e não é possível retornar os tipos anônimos, vou criar a classe mesmo, senão vai ficar complexo demais e para mexer no futuro vai ser difícil :D

Answer (score 3):

Acredito não ser possível você retornar um tipo anonimo.

> Você não pode declarar que um campo, uma propriedade, um evento ou um
>   tipo de retorno de um método tem um tipo anônimo. Da mesma forma, não
>   pode declarar que um parâmetro formal de um método, propriedade,
>   construtor ou indexador tem um tipo anônimo. Para passar um tipo
>   anônimo ou uma coleção que contenha tipos anônimos, como um argumento
>   para um método, você pode declarar o parâmetro como objeto type. No
>   entanto, isso anula a finalidade dos tipos fortes. **Se você precisa
>   armazenar os resultados da consulta ou passá-los fora do limite do
>   método, considere o uso de uma estrutura ou classe com denominação
>   comum em vez de um tipo anônimo.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb397696.aspx

O que você pode fazer é criar uma class para seu retorno, podendo fipublic

```
List<RetornoModel> ListarAnonimo()
{
    //Especifica um "template" para o tipo retornado.
    var lista = new[]
    {
        new RetornoModel
        {
            Nome = "",
            Idade = 0,
            Salario = 0.0m
        }
    }.ToList();

    lista.Clear();

    //Adiciona um item.
    lista.Add(new RetornoModel()
    {
        Nome = "Gato",
        Idade = 25,
        Salario = 3000000.0m
    });

    return lista;
}

class RetornoModel
{
    public int Idade { get;  set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Salario { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Eu não negativei a resposta... Neste caso eu estaria retornando uma classe, eu precisaria retornar um tipo anonimo ou uma lista enumerada com os objetos anonimo contendo as propriedades. Eu possuo varias consultas se eu for ter que criar uma classe para cada vai me dar muito trabalho :(

Comment: Eu particularmente preferiria seguir nesse caminho de criar uma classe para cada retorno de minhas consultas, mas pesquisando mais um pouco encontrei essa possibilidade http://stackoverflow.com/a/7494146/2221388, mas mesmo assim você naõ estaria retornando um tipo anonimo e sim o dynamic

Comment: Pablo pesquei a respeito do retorno de tipos anônimos e não há uma forma de fazer o q eu desejo. Vc e o bigown me mostrou que é melhor criar a classe modelo mesmo so com os campos desejados, mesmo q de mais código, e mas parece que vale a pena criar a classe. +1 :)