# Qual nome é dado em C# quando usamos a expressão "new {}"?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Quando eu vi o uso da expressão `new {}` eu me lembrei do Javascript, onde eu usar `new Object` e `{}` são equivalentes.

Apenas para fins de estudos, fiz umas comparações, pra saber se Csharp seguia a mesma ideia do Javascript, mas parece que eu estava errado:

```
var obj1 = new {};

var obj2 = new object(){
};

Console.WriteLine(obj1.GetType()); // <>f__AnonymousType0

Console.WriteLine(obj2.GetType()); // System.Object
```

Nesse caso, qual é o nome dado a `new {}`, já que parece não ser a mesma coisa que `object`?

Qual é a relação de `new {}` com `object` em C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como a mensagem de retorno do `GetType()` mostra, é um tipo anônimo ([*anonymous type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)), é um tipo que não tem nome no seu código. Claro que internamente tem um nome porque não é possível ter um tipo sem nome no CLR, mas o seu código não vê e não se importa com ele. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183594/101).

Em C# todos os os tipos são derivados de `Object`, inclusive este. `Object` não tem uma estrutura, não tem estado, o tipo anônimo pode ter. Este especificamente não faz sentido algum, não tem utilidade por não ter estado. Tipos anônimos são sobre estado.

Em geral, hoje em dia, deve usar-se menos este tipo e usar mais a [tupla da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101) ([não a da biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94882/101)), mas em alguns casos ele ainda é útil, até por compatibilidade. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207800/101).

Tuplas só devem ser usadas quando realmente é o melhor mecanismo, tipos anônimos devem ser usados menos ainda.

Quase sempre criar um `Object` "concreto" também não faz sentido. `Object` provavelmente nem deveria ser uma classe.

Para C# ter uma semântica semelhante ao JS deve usar [`dynamic`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101), mas [é desencorajado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203656/101) sempre que possível. [Cada linguagem tem sua filosofia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).